# The scroll event of HTMLDivElement stop firing in ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I just upgrade my app from ionic 3 to ionic 5 and angular 8. 
I have a chat page in which I use the croll event of HTMLDivElement as follow:

```
<div class="white-board" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
```

Since I upgrade the ionic the scroll event stopped working. 
Any idea what would be the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1-) Change `(scroll)` by `(ionScroll)`

[From Migration Guide he explains:](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/BREAKING.md#version-5x)

> In order to solve this we added CSS classes. Rather than support CSS
>   attributes in certain frameworks and classes in others, we decided to
>   remove the CSS attributes and support what works in all of them,
>   classes, for consistency. **In addition to this, changing to classes
>   prefixed with *ion* avoids conflict with native attributes and user's
>   CSS.** In the latest version of Ionic 4, there are deprecation warnings
>   printed in the console to show what the new classes are, and the
>   documentation has been updated since support for classes was added to
>   remove all references to attributes:

Comment: i tried but not working too